# Can't Delete Safari Webdata

Tags: macos, safari

I cleared my Safari cookies and web data using the recommended method `Safari > Preferences > Privacy > Manage Website Data... > Remove All`. No matter how many times I do this, `donotcall.gov` data doesn't get removed. This data is stored locally apparently, but I couldn't find the exact location. Can anyone offer any insight?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Untested* - Copied from [Apple Discussion thread - Safari cookies: where are they located](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5196860?answerId=31602996022#31602996022)

> For macOS Sierra 10.12.6 and Safari 11.0.1, most likely, the cookies
> and references to websites that survive clicking -- the "Remove" and
> "Remove All" buttons in the Safari->Preferences->Privacy->Manage
> Website Data pane -- reside in each user's or account's library.
>
> In the Utilities/Terminal.app, type
> `rm -frP ~/Library/Safari/Databases/* ~/Library/Safari/LocalStorage/*`
>
> That command line will terminate with extreme prejudice the files
> where those persistent annoyances reside.
>
> Unix shell command line to English translation:
>
> 1. rm is the name of the Unix command that deletes files from the filesystem.
> 2. f in -frP forces rm to work quietly without complaints or asking for permission before doing anything.
> 3. r in -frP instructs rm to traverse or walk the filesystem sub-tree beneath each of the pathnames that follow.
> 4. P in -frP tells rm to overwrite each file or directory with junk before unlinking either a file or directory from its parent directory.
> 5. The ~ (tilde) before each pathname is an abbreviation for $HOME or "my home directory."
> 6. The / (slash) separates directory names in pathnames; do not replace it with any other character.
> 7. The * (asterisk) after each pathname is an abbreviation for "everything that resides beyond."
>
> Running that command line from inside an AppleScript when Safari is
> shut down would be ideal, but if that isn't possible, running that
> command from a cron file once a day would be acceptable.

Comment: Thank you @Tetsujin. Probably worth a try, at least the second location (`LocalStorage`). I think I read somewhere it's not good to mess with the `Databases` folder.  I ended up doing essentially the same operation manually, as suggested in this post: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253516809?login=true&page=1. I can't mark your answer as 'Accepted' since I did not try it.